# Get closest element from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, bisection

My program generates the following list (excerpt):

```
my_list = [{'x': 1764, 'y': 18320, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e2443'},
           {'x': 1764, 'y': 20030, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e2591'},
           {'x': 1807, 'y': 12650, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e1362'},
           {'x': 2243, 'y': 20120, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e2609'},
           {'x': 2243, 'y': 22685, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e2769'},
           {'x': 2257, 'y': 12560, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e1380'},
           {'x': 2688, 'y': 20210, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e2625'},
           {'x': 2707, 'y': 10040, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e1194'},
           {'x': 2707, 'y': 12650, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e1398'},
           {'x': 2707, 'y': 14720, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e1571'},
           {'x': 2901, 'y': 18140, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e2475'}]
```

It is already sorted by the value of the 'x'-key. I am trying to write a method, that returns a tuple of two elements of this list for a given coordinate `(xPos, yPos)`:

- The nearest element to the left (`x <= xPos`)
- The nearest element to the right (`x > xPos`)

The distance is simply the euclidean distance ("Pythagoras"). A second parameter for the function is the maximum distance allowed:

```
def getNearest(noteList, posX, posY, maxDistance):
    [...]
    return leftElement, rightElement
```

I have tried to use the bisect function to get the insertion point of the closest element to `xPos` as well as for `xPos - maxDistance` (case 'left') and `xPos + maxDistance` (case 'right) respectively in order to narrow down the search area. Then I calculated the distance for every remaining element in this sliced list

Somehow this feels very unelegant. Is there any better way of doing this?

**EDIT:**
Maybe I was not very clear with my intention: I need two elements of the list. The nearest element in the '2D pane' to the left and one to the right. Thus I need to consider the y-coordinate as well.

It might happen (acutally almost every time) that the closest element in regard to its x-coordinate is way more far away than an element with a close-by y-coordinate.

Comment: For an efficient search you could look into kd-trees.

Comment: Should it be efficient or is the set of points always low?

Comment: It's roughly about 500 entries, so rather low.

Comment: Do you want go get the `id` as result or just the coordinates?

Comment: I would need the entire element, means the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to merge my initial idea with a few suggestions from the answers. This is what I came up with:

```
class translatedDictList(object):
    def __init__(self, dictList, key):
        self.dictList = dictList
        self.key = key

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.dictList[item][self.key]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.dictList.__len__()

def getNearest(self, symbolList, pos, maxDistance):
    translatedList = translatedDictList(symbolList, 'x')

    splitIndex = bisect.bisect(translatedList, pos[0])
    minIndex = bisect.bisect(translatedList, pos[0] - maxDistance)
    maxIndex = bisect.bisect(translatedList, pos[0] + maxDistance)

    # Euclidean distance acutally not needed anymore!
    leftElement = min(symbolList[minIndex:splitIndex],
                      key=lambda n: abs(n['x'] - pos[0]) +
                                    abs(n['y'] - pos[1]))
    rightElement = min(symbolList[splitIndex:maxIndex],
                       key=lambda n: abs(n['x'] - pos[0]) +
                                     abs(n['y'] - pos[1]))

    return leftElement, rightElement

print(getNearest(self.symbolsSorted, (1200, 1500), 1000))
```

Maybe there is a smarter way of translating the `symbolList` in order to use `bisect()`?

It should be `o(log*n)` and as far as I can tell I don't even need to calculate the euclidean distance anymore because I am only comparing and not interested in the actual distance.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a good solution, but from the way you described it, I don't see a need to do more than a single bisect.

`bisect_left` already returns the index of the element such that your first condition is satisfied (`x <= xPos - maxDistance`). From there, I'd simply iterate the elements to the right one by one until you reach `x > xPos + maxDistance`.

This will probably yield better performance considering the CPU cache, because you're [iterating adjacent positions instead of jumping around](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)

If you start processing a large number of points or `maxDistance`, this algorithm will probably not suffice. In that case, you should look into using a [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), as wenzul suggested.

Comment: Yes, but `bisect_left` only considers the `x`coordinate. I need the closest elements (one to the left, one to the right) in regard to `x` and `y`.

Comment: @sonovice Gotcha. Same principle applies - I've amended the answer

Answer (score 1):

you could use `min()` to find the nearest elements on both sides of `posX`, in regards to their Euclidean distance.

```
>>>import math
>>>def getNearest(noteList, posX, posY):
...    leftElement = min([i for i in my_list if i['x'] <= posX], key=lambda x:abs(math.sqrt((x['x']- posX)**2+(x['y']- posY)**2)))
...    rightElement = min([i for i in my_list if i['x'] > posX], key=lambda x:abs(math.sqrt((x['x']- posX)**2+(x['y']- posY)**2)))
...    return (leftElement, rightElement)


>>> getNearest(my_list, 2000, 2000)
({'y': 12650, 'x': 1807, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e1362'}, {'y': 10040, 'x': 2707, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e1194'})

>>> getNearest(my_list, 2000, 20000)
({'y': 20030, 'x': 1764, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e2591'}, {'y': 20120, 'x': 2243, 'class': 'note', 'id': 'd1e2609'})
```

Where the `Key` is the Euclidean distance between each element on the 2D pane, and the element passed to the function, ie `(posX, PosY)`.

Comment: This turns the `O( log(n) )` algorithm into `O( n )`

Comment: Yes that is true, but no other solution had actually accounted for the Euclidean distance. They only took distance from `x` into account